# Is `<-` actually slower than `=`?

Tags: r, performance, microbenchmark

Is the following difference in execution times genuine?

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(x = NULL, x <- NULL, times = 100e3)

Unit: nanoseconds
      expr min lq    mean median uq  max neval
         x   0  0 0.60819      0  0 8426 1e+05
 x <- NULL   0  0 1.75101      0  1 8727 1e+05
```

I get a warning that about 75% of the evaluations had a nonpositive execution time. Nonetheless, each time I have run this, I get a consistent result: `x = NULL` is faster than `x <- NULL` on average.

Comment: Both [call](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/names.c#L100) the [same C function](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/eval.c#L2685). There is no performance difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `microbenchmark` functions parses the `...` arguments in different ways. The `x=NULL` is never interpreted as an assigment, but as a function argument.
So you, as far as I can tell, are not really measuring the time for the first argument.

You need to do something like this:

```
 microbenchmark(test1 = `=`(x, NULL), test2 = `<-`(x, NULL), times = 100e3)
```

or as @Roland describes in the comments.
This calls the appropriate functions behind the assignment operators.

Comment: `microbenchmark(test1 = {x = NULL}, test2 = {x <- NULL}, times = 100e3)`

Answer (score 3):

These statements don't do the same thing in this context. You will see this if you run for example

```
microbenchmark(y = NULL, x <- NULL, times = 100e3)
```

This created an object `x`, but no object `y`. You can run the test you ment to run using brackets:

```
microbenchmark({y = NULL}, {x <- NULL}, times = 100e3)
```